# Persisting @ManyToOne with optional Foreign Keys?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I want to persist an `@Entity` having a `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn` reference, which should be optional.

But when I try to persist the following `Person` class where `locationId` is set, but `address` rerference is not set, I'm getting a `PSQLException: voilates foreign key constraints`exception.

My class looks as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int locationId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_address"), nullable = true)
    private AddressEntity address;
}

@Entity
public class AddressEnity {
    @Id
    private int locationId;

    //street, zip, town etc

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<Person> persons;
}
```

The schema generated by hibernate:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  location_id interger NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_address FOREIGN KEY (location_id)
    REFERENCES addresses (location_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE address(
  location_id integer NOT NULL,
  //street, zip, town, etc
   CONSTRAINT location_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (location_id)
);
```

Question: isn't is possible to save the `locationId` explicit, but omitting the address entity? (which might come in later, but not known at this stage).

Comment: what about `location_id interger NOT NULL` in table definition?

Comment: Yes exactly, the `location_id` is never null and always known, but the location_id data for `address` table might not be known or later added.

Comment: I think, `locationId` property of `Person` class will never be saved, because it is hasn't mapping annotation. Names of field in table `person.location_id` and in class `Person.locationId` are different. And you have `location_id interger NOT NULL` in `person` table as well.

Comment: It's just a typo as this of course only an example and more a conceptual question.